# OSPF Convergence

Tags: networking, routes, network-protocols, ospf

Network convergence as the process of synchronizing network forwarding tables after a topology change.Please can some explain clearly what are the steps in `OSPF` Convergence and how is it better than RIP Convergence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSPF is link-state algorithm (it uses Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm) hence has the view of entire network. This ensures that every router in the network know the full network topology and can decide which routes to use to different destinations (subnets). Convergence of OSPF is dependent on OSPF timers (for better understanding http://www2.ensc.sfu.ca/~ljilja/cnl/pdf/hubert.pdf , this has details on convergence tests).

RIP is a distance vector protocol and distance vector has count-to-infinity problem. RIP uses network diameter concept to avoid this problem. The maximum network diameter can be 15 in RIP hence hop count (measure of distance in RIP) is limited to 15 and this avoids count-to-infinity problem. Convergence of RIP is hence (in worst case) equal to network-diameter or 15 to be precise.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

OSPF convergence takes place in the following ways
1-Router Identities are first found out , it happens in the following ways
a)The highest IP address on the router's active loopback interfaces is used 
b)If no loopback interface is present the highest IP address on its active interfaces is used when the router boots up.

2-Next Step Negihbour relationships are found out-An OSPF router learns about its OSPF neighbours and builds its adjacency tables and topology tables by sharing LSA's.Criteria for 2 OSPF routers to be connected to each other
a)The area number of the 2 routers must be the same
b)The hello and dead timers for both the routers must be the same
c)The OSPF password on both of them must be the same
d)MTU sizes on both the interfaces must be the same

Neighbours are formed by the process known as exchange process
1-Down State-No ospf info exchanged
2-Init State-Another router's LSA hello packet is recieved
3-2way state-Unidirectional reply has taken place.

3-Electing designated and BackupDesignated routers- Router with the highest priority becomes the DR for the segment,If there is a tie the router with the highest routerID will become the DR,the second highest IP address becomes the BDR.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you go to driving to London City. Suddenly there is a road block.
User OSPF have the full london city map (topology)
User RIP only depend on Police traffic signal and sign board at various junction. (only next hop information)
Which user will reach his destination faster in the event there is road block, traffic jam etc.